# Is there any API that can bring spilt view mode to full view mode

Tags: ios, multitasking, splitview, multitasking-gestures

As we known, IOS 9 support split view mode. Is there any API that can bring spilt view mode to full view mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in any method/button action, use following code

```
self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
```

Comment: Not UISplitViewController, It's split view mode in IOS 9. Thanks the same.